# Pass PageRequest object from Angular 4 to Spring Controller

Tags: angular, pagination, controller, paging

Is there any solution to pass from `Angular 4` `PageRequest` object which will be an argument to the `REST` controller? Be aware that I don't mean using `@PathVariable`.

Below there is a `controller` which has a `PageRequest` in arg - so now I am wondering how to create that object from `Angular 4`?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Page<Item> getAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
            return itemService.findAll(pageRequest);
        }
```

Comment: I think it's a normal request body. Try to send as reest body debug that if it's available on the spring controller. Although not tried myself. Just a suggestion

Comment: In your Angular use this object in the get request: `let pageRequest = {
        page: 0,
        size: 10,
        direction: 'desc'
 };`